# How do I fix the "no such partition" error from GRUB?

Tags: grub2, encryption

When I boot my computer I get the following error:

```
Welcome to GRUB!
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

My system has Windows 7 and Ubuntu in dual-boot; Ubuntu is installed with full-disk encryption. My computer does not have a CD drive.

Comment: Are you selecting Windows boot manager? Have you tried running boot repair?

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn off your computer in the middle of disk formatting? If so you might need to fix your filesystem or, if you can afford to lose the data, just reinstall ubuntu and reformat the drive during installation.